# Use a for loop/ accumulator pattern

Tags: python, string

How to write a function emphasize() that takes as an input a string s and print it with spaces inserted between adjacent letters. This is what I tried

```
def emphasize (s):
  for aWord in s:
    print(s.replace [1:-1])
```

Comment: You should show us what you tried

Comment: My first time using this and it didn't print correctly, but FOR and PRINT are on different lines.

Comment: Try the answer. It should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to

```
def emphasize(s):
  print(" ".join(s))
```

Comment: Hi Tony; your answer might be correct, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, and perhaps including links to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thank you